# How to construct data, from Observables value, and return a Observable<Response> after the HTTP call?

Tags: http, angular, typescript, observable

When constructing a data object that contains values which are resolved from an Observable, I'm unable to figure how to return the `Observable<Response>`.

I've tried using the `forkJoin()`, to resolve the values first, and then `subscribe` to it, and return the `this.http.post()...` call. This, however, makes it not possible to subscribe to the function itself `fetchData().subscribe( ... )`. I'm clearly missing something.

**So, how do I construct a data object, which contains resolved `Observable` values, and subsequently return the `Observable<Response>` object?**

```js
// Simplified example 

fetchData() { 

  // Construct the data
  var data = {
      v1 : this.getValueFromObservable1(),
      v2 : this.getValueFromObservable2()
  };

  // Make the call, return the Observable<Response> object
  return this.http
      .post( 'api/authorization', JSON.stringify(data) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
fetchData() {
    return this.getValueFromObservable1()
    .mergeMap(v1 => 
          this.getValueFromObservable2()
          .map(v2 => { v1: v1, v2: v2})
    );
}
```

Comment: The last two lines in my example form the bottleneck, how can `this.post( ... )` a.k.a. the `Observable<Response>` be returned, knowing that the `data` object depends on "`Observable` data"? Do you suggest something like: `this.http.post( url, fetchData() )`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The idea was to wait for the first, then for the 2nd event and then build the object. There might be better ways like `zip()` where both requests can run "parallel` but I don't use TS and don't know the rxjs operators very well.